# Java regex to find two upper case letters, followed by one space and seven digits

Tags: java, regex

I want to find a regex for the following pattern: `"AA XXXXXXX"` (two characters, one space and 7 digits).

Example: `"AA 1234567"`.

Now I can't find the answer.

Comment: My recommendation would be to [try reading a regex tutorial sometime](http://regular-expressions.info/).

Comment: The java pattern for an uppercase letter is `\p{Lu}`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The pattern you want is:

```
[a-zA-Z]{2} [0-9]{7}
```

exactly two chars (upper or lower case) followed by space followed by exactly 7 digits.

If the characters can only be uppercase like in the sample string:

```
[A-Z]{2} [0-9]{7}
```

In Java:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[A-Z]{2} [0-9]{7}");
Matcher m = p.matcher("AA 1234567");
boolean b = m.matches();
```